# Magento2 Custom product attribute value do not show on frontend until we resave products

Tags: database, magento, caching, magento2

I need some help related to Magento Ecommerce. We have a script to save product custom value. The script runs fine because i did checked in the admin that the value is inserted for that product and also checked in the database and it all worked good.

But now, when we see that product on frontend, it does not get affect. I did re-index, flushed cache, removed var/generation and other folders in var but no luck at all. Also checked that the specific website is selected.

But now when i manually re-save the product from the backend (without modifying anything), it worked very well and affected on frontend.

Can anyone tell me please what can be the issue. We often face this type of issue in Magento and also in Magento2.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have your crons working?

Comment: Yaa crons working fine. But i am not running my script with cron. I am  running script on my browser.